# Form validation not working properly in cakePHP 2.4.6

Tags: cakephp

In version 2.2.1 I could validate a form using rules and custom messages like below. But somehow the password rule isn't working as of version 2.3. Any help what I might be doing wrong here?

Model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
public $validate = array(
'password' => array(
    'rule' => array ('between', 5, 10 ),
        'message' => 'Password must between 5 and 10 characters long'
    )
);
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {

    $this->data['User']['password'] = Security::hash($this->data['User']['password'], 'sha1', true);

return true;

}
}
```

View:

```
    <?php

echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('label' => 'First name'));
echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array('label' => 'Last name'));
echo $this->Form->input('adminrole', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => 'Is admin?<br /><br />'));
echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => 'E-mail address'));
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Password'));
echo $this->Form->input('picturethumb', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => 'Profile picture'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save');

?>
```

Please bare in mind that this exact same code validates correctly in 2.2.1

Controller:

```
    class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        $users = $this->User->find('all');
        $this->set('users', $users);

    }
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->save($this->request->data);
            $this->redirect('/users');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please, update your question with your view file and the whole $validate properties.

Comment: Model and View looks good. Problem might be on your Controller. Update your question with UsersController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->redirect('/users');
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Opps... Something is wrong');
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanx a lot Fazal. Not really getting why this was changed in recent releases, but well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with cake sometime, but I remember had this problem before. The problem is, the cakephp will create a hash of password, so when Model get password is already big. What I did in time was make another validate, like password_tmp and use it like field and create the hash by myself in controller for the real field password.

Comment: Well the thing is that the hashing is done after. And the script doesn't return a error message, but also doesn't safe the data

Comment: Just tested by deleting the validation and the password isn't hashed

Comment: As Cakephp 2.*, Hashing need to do manually basically on beforeSave(). So, password never hashed automatically.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. But it goes to the redirect page, and doesn't store the values, but also doesn't give a validation message. I have just added this hashing to the initial code I gave in my question

Comment: I didnt remember about the auto hash in password, my mystake. I'm trying to thinking what is happening.  Have you tried to debug() data on beforeValidate or tried to see if your rules works with another field?

Comment: Yes I did Scoup. Also when I use the exact lines of code on version 2.2.1 I do get the error messages